# Get BizTalk message flow exception via Powershell?

Tags: exception, powershell, biztalk, operations

Is there a BizTalk.Operations class or other BizTalk class such that I can retrieve the HAT Message Flow Exception?

The exception, not the ErrorInfo or ErrorDesc property, that I'm referring to is found in:
Go to BizTalk Group Hub (2010)
   1. Select the 'Grouped by Service Name' link
   2. Right Click on a Suspended item (except Routing Failures), then select 'Message Flow'

The HAT Message Flow form loads with properties e.g.; Activity ID, Error Info, Error Description, etc.

There's one last property named Exceptions at the bottom of the list. Although, Exception is not displayed like other properties or in text, but rather via a hyperlink to the exception details.

I want to retrieve this Exception, and preferrably via PowerShell, but do not know which class it resides in after looking in MSDN Operations namespace. I'd prefer to access this via Powershell's Add-Type rather than WMI.

Thanks

Comment: Could you get the same data from the Windows Application EventLog.  There are easy to use Powershell commands for reading the EventLog, then maybe you could RegEx or parse to find the data you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks, Neal. Well, yes and no. I was able to retrieve the Exception details for some apps, but not for others. I need to run more tests. I think the reason that some BizTalk exceptions were not logged has to do with the Propagate Fault Message flag. If the flag is disabled or unchecked, then exceptions don't get logged in the Windows Application Event Logs and vice versa.